# div width height issue with css

Tags: html, css, height

for some reason, the blue div is going way farther than the "end" of the page, and im getting a vertical scroll bar. obviously i shouldn't be. any ideas?
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="body">
<div id="wrap">

<!--header starts-->
<div id="header">
<div id="name">
<h1>Comp <span>any</span> Name</h1>
</div><!--end name-->   
<div id="nav"><br>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="programs.html">Our Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ol>
</div><!--end nav-->
</div><!--end header-->
<!--header ends-->

<!--content1 starts-->
<div id="content1">
<img src="images/placeholder.png" width="400" height="323" alt="logo"> 
<div id="imgright">
<h2>What We Do</h2>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et 
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
    aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui o
    fficia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<div id="button">
<h4>Request A Program</h4>
</div><!--end button-->
</div><!--end imgright-->
</div><!--end content1-->
<!--content1 ends-->

<!--content2 starts-->
<div id="content2">
<div id="one">
  <img src="images/arrow.png" width="16" height="14" alt="arrow1">
  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p> 
</div><!--end one-->

<div id="two">
  <img src="images/arrow.png" width="16" height="14" alt="arrow2"> 
  <h3>About Us</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p>
</div><!--end two-->

<div id="three">
  <img src="images/arrow.png" width="16" height="14" alt="arrow3"> 
  <h3> View Our Programs</h3>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam"</p>
</div><!--end three-->  
</div><!--end content2-->
<!--content2 ends-->

<!--footer starts-->
<div id="footer">
<h5>Insert some footer information, copyright information also</h5>    
</div>    <!--end footer-->
<!--footer ends-->
</div><!--end wrap-->
</div><!--end body-->
<div id="blue">
</div><!--end blue-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#body{
background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
margin-top:-25px;
padding:0;  
}
#wrap{
border-width:3px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:white;
width:1024px;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top:5px;
}

#header h1{
font-size:36px;
font-family: Terminal, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: white;
}

span{
font-size:100px;
color:black;
font-family:brush script std, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#nav{
margin-top:-110px;
margin-bottom:75px;
margin-right:40px;
}

#nav ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#nav li {
display: block;
float: right;
}

#nav a {
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 3px;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font: 24px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: white;
}

#nav a:hover { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: black;
}

#content1 img{
margin-left:25px;
}

#imgright{
margin-left:445px;
margin-top:-389px;
}

#button h4{
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:24px;
color:white;
}

h2{
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:48px;
}

#imgright p{
color: white;
font-size:24px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:20px;
}

#content2{
background-color:#2e3192;
}

#one, #two, #three{width:341.3px;}

#one h3{
font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}
#one p{
font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}

#two h3{
font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}
#two p{
font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}

#three h3{
font-family:trajan pro, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;    
}

#three p{
font-family:vijaya, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
}

#one{
margin-top:50px;
}

#two{
margin-top:-104px;
margin-left:360px;
}

#three{
margin-top:-408px;
margin-left:720px;
}

#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
color:white;
}

#footer h5{
margin-left:300px;
}

#blue{
position:absolute;
top:500px;
z-index:-1;
background-color:#2e3192;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

This is what it currently looks like:
[image: currently looks like]

this is what it should look like, no scrollbar and stops at the bottom.
[image: should look like]

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two ways:

**Remove height**

```
#wrap{
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
    width:1024px;
    height:100%; // Make this auto. height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```

Or

**Overflow Hidden**

```
#body{
    background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin-top:-25px;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden; // Add this
}
```

Comment: For some reason the suto did not work but hidden overflow did, another question real quick , when zoomed in. my footer div will overflow upon the rest of my content. and ideas on how to keep it from doing that?

Comment: You have a fiddle or something? Or the live website itself?